# How to get Angular 2 communication between child and parent component to work?

Tags: angular, eventemitter

Parent template

```
<problem-form *ngIf=showProblemView (addProblem)=problemAdd($event)></problem-form>
```

Child Component

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Output() addproblem = new EventEmitter<string>();
onClick() {
    this.addproblem.emit('something')
    console.log('onSubmit')
    this.active = false;
}
```

Parent event handler

```
problemAdd($event) {
    debugger;
    console.log('eventString ')
}
```

I know that the child event IS emitting from following the debugger.  My understanding is that the parent is not capturing the emitted child event.  Any Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your child:

```
@Output() addproblem = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

In the parent:

```
<problem-form *ngIf=showProblemView (addProblem)=problemAdd($event)></problem-form>
                                        ^
```

Notice the capital P.

Angular 2 is case-sensitive.

Either rename the property to `addProblem` or the output handler to `(addproblem)`.

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior I have to change my VSCode find settings to be case-sensitive.  StackOverflow wants me to wait 7 minutes to accept the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @tibbus for your response yesterday.  I took that question down because I was manually typing in my code to stackoverflow.  Here I did copy/paste.  But in both cases the error was due to a misnamed variable.